# A better query for LEFT JOIN on two tables and getting only matching results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an `order` table that is associated with two join tables: `order_buyer` and `order_seller`.

The table structure looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order` (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    -- some fields...

    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order_seller (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    order_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    seller_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_order_seller_order_id FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES `order` (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_order_seller_seller_id FOREIGN KEY (seller_id) REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order_buyer (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    order_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    buyer_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_order_buyer_order_id FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES `order` (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_order_buyer_buyer_id FOREIGN KEY (buyer_id) REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

If I am a buyer viewing my order history, I want to get all orders where the `order_buyer.buyer_id` is equal to my user ID. Same thing goes for the seller.

But my query is such that I don't know if it's the buyer or the seller making the query; I just have a user ID. So I need one of them to match, and if one matches then I want to collect that order.

The following query does not work because it gives me every single order:

```
SELECT `order`.*
FROM `order`
LEFT JOIN order_seller
    ON order_seller.seller_id = 1
    AND order_seller.order_id = order.id
LEFT JOIN order_buyer
    ON order_buyer.buyer_id = 1
    AND order_buyer.order_id = order.id
WHERE order.status = "PENDING"
```

The query below solves the problem above by removing the `AND` from the joins and making it a `WHERE IN` clause on the result set:

```
SELECT `order`.*
FROM `order`
LEFT JOIN order_seller
    ON order_seller.seller_id = 1
LEFT JOIN order_buyer
    ON order_buyer.buyer_id = 1
WHERE order.status = "PENDING"
    AND order.id IN (order_buyer.order_id, order_seller.order_id)
```

My question is, is there a better query to achieve the same thing? This seems kind of dirty to me. Feels unnatural.

Comment: qq: why there is a group by but no aggregate function? secondly; can you put sample data and your expected result? it is harder to analyze data without samples.

Comment: Sorry the group by was an artifact from something else I was doing. Removed that. Will update with test data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just combine the two queries:

```
SELECT `order`.*
FROM `order`
LEFT JOIN order_seller
    ON order_seller.seller_id = 1
    AND order_seller.order_id = order.id
LEFT JOIN order_buyer
    ON order_buyer.buyer_id = 1
    AND order_buyer.order_id = order.id
WHERE order.status = "PENDING"
    AND order.id IN (order_buyer.order_id, order_seller.order_id)
```

It should be faster than your second query, but return the same result.

You can also change the last condition to

```
COALESCE(order_buyer.order_id, order_seller.order_id) IS NOT NULL
```

which would be essentially the same as Gordon's first query.

However - The problem here is that the engine will need to read all pending orders before it can filter them by userID. And you would have the same problem with EXISTS subqueries.

Instead I would use a UNION ALL query:

```
SELECT `order`.*
FROM `order`
JOIN order_seller ON order_seller.order_id = order.id
WHERE order.status = "PENDING" AND order_seller.seller_id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT `order`.*
FROM `order`
JOIN order_buyer ON order_buyer.order_id = order.id
WHERE order.status = "PENDING" AND order_buyer.buyer_id = 1
```

To avoid to much code duplication you can use a UNION ALL subquery:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM (
    SELECT order_id FROM order_seller WHERE seller_id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT order_id FROM order_buyer WHERE buyer_id = 1
) x
JOIN `order` o ON o.id = x.order_id
WHERE o.status = "PENDING"
```

You will need at least an index on `order(status)`. Since the primary key (`order.id`) is an implicit part of it, the index can be used for the JOIN-ON and the WHERE clause at the same time. For the other tables the indexes on `order_seller(seller_id)` and `order_buyer(buyer_id)` might be fine. But composite indexes on `order_seller(seller_id, order_id)` and `order_buyer(buyer_id, order_id)` would be better.

Comment: Chose this answer since it goes more in depth and shows the tradeoffs from multiple approaches.

Comment: Had to change `UNION ALL` to just `UNION` because otherwise there are duplicates where the user is both the buyer and the seller (purchased their own item).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the first version, by adding a `where` clause:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM `order` o LEFT JOIN
     order_seller os
     ON os.seller_id = 1 AND
        os.order_id = o.id LEFT JOIN
     order_buyer ob
     ON ob.buyer_id = 1 AND
        ob.order_id = o.id
WHERE o.status = 'PENDING' AND
      (os.order_id IS NOT NULL OR ob.order_id IS NOT NULL);
```

However, I would write the query using `exists`:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM `order` o
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM order_seller os
              WHERE os.seller_id = 1 AND os.order_id = o.id
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM order_buyer ob
              WHERE ob.buyer_id = 1 AND ob.order_id = o.id
             )
WHERE o.status = 'PENDING' ;
```

For performance, you want indexes on each of the tables on `(order_id, buyer_id)` and `(order_id, seller_id)`.

Comment: Nice, I like the EXISTS approach. Also, aren't those id's already indexed with my foreign key constraints? Please check updated question with schema included. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Lansana . . . MySQL (unlike other databases) creates indexes for foreign key constraints.  Those indexes are probably fine.

Comment: Sweet, MySQL is what I'm using. Thanks again.

Comment: @Lansana  No - You don't have those indexes. The FK definitions would create single column indexes `(order_id)` and `(seller_id)`. This is not the same as the composite (multiple columns) index `(order_id, seller_id)`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel . . . But the single column index will probably do a good job as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If those are one-to-many relations (`order_id` is logically unique), then yes - the index on `order_id` would be fine. Though not optimal, because you will need a second lookup to check the `seller_id`. I would probably just define `order_id` as PK and remove `id`.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like

```
select order.*
  from order
 where order.status = 'PENDING'
   and order.id in (
     select s.order_id from order_seller s where s.seller_id = 1
     union all
     select b.order_id from order_buyer b where b.buyer_id = 1)
```

or change it using exists

```
select o.*
  from order o
 where o.status = 'PENDING'
   and (
     exists (select 1 
               from order_seller s 
              where s.seller_id = 1 and s.order_id = o.order_id)
     or
     exists (select 1 
               from order_buyer b 
              where b.buyer_id = 1 and b.order_id = o.order_id))
```